# Run .sh script using Google Cloud SDK shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to automate deploying code to my 3 GCE Linux VM's. I read this article [Scripting with gcloud: a beginner’s guide to automating GCP tasks](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/management-tools/scripting-with-gcloud-a-beginners-guide-to-automating-gcp-tasks), it shows how to make a script. Now I assume that means saving the code as a .sh file (it even has a shebang on top), now how do I run that. Do I type the script file name in the Google Cloud SDK Shell? I tried it, it does not seem to work. can someone help me? I will really appreciate.

Here is an image of my google cloud shell where I am trying to use the script files.[image: cmd]

Comment: my script is like this: `#!/bin/bash
gcloud compute --project "myproject" scp C:\Users\******\Desktop\publish.zip --zone "us-east1-c" "****":publish.zip`. I put it in a file `myscript.sh` in the same folder as the google cloud shell. I then type the file name in the cloud shell. it opens a blank cmd window which closes immediately. but the script does not work. it does not copy the publish.zip file to my VM. ruing this cmd directly in the same shell does work

Comment: I Edited My Question, john

Comment: What I am talking about is the cloud SDK shell you download into your computer. it is called the google cloud SDK shell. but it's used from my computer and it uses the windows paths.

Comment: Remember that on windows you can't run .sh scripts naively (maybe with windows power shell?), you might as well use a .bat file. Also I think you are confused about what gcloud is, if you want to automate the deploy you have also to think what happens on the other side.

Answer (score 1):

You're able to [install Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) on variety of operation systems such as Linux, macOS and Windows. After that, you'll be able to use same commands like `gcloud`, `gsutil` and `bq`. Meanwhile, scripting relies on the command-line interpreters: you can use [`bash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) with Linux and macOS, but for Windows you should use [`cmd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) and [`PowerShell`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell). You can run examples provided at the [article](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/management-tools/scripting-with-gcloud-a-beginners-guide-to-automating-gcp-tasks), you've mentioned, and at the documentation [Scripting gcloud CLI commands](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/scripting-gcloud) with `bash` on Linux and macOS, so the error messages you've got were expected. You can't run `.sh` scripts on windows naively, as it was mentioned by *@Pievis* at the comment section.

**As a possible workaround** you can [install Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) for Windows 10 (usually you can [choose between WSL2 and WSL1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions), but it depends on build version of your Windows 10) to get some [interoperability between Windows and Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop).

**If you need to transfer files to you VM instances** please follow the documentation [Transferring files to VMs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files).

**If you are interested in automation with GCP**, please have a look on the documentation [Infrastructure as code](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/infrastructure-as-code) to "automate repeatable tasks like provisioning, configuration, and deployments".